# How to access session data from script which is posted with cURL ?

Tags: php, session, curl, session-cookies

I'm using curl to simulate login:

```
$url = 'http://localhost/Login.php';
$fields = array(
        'username' => urlencode('test_username'),
        'password' => urlencode('test_password'),
);

//url-ify the data for the POST
$fields_string = '';
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

// receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);

// How to access $_SESSION['username'] from here ??
```

The login.php script is adding the username to the session:

```
<?php
namespace Login;
session_start();
// some code
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
```

How can I access the session data from the first script

Comment: So you want to use curl to login to a script by posting the username and password to login.php. That login.php page sets a session['username'] that you want to access from the curl script. Can i ask why? don't you already know the user name since you had to post it via the curl script?

Comment: in login.php I verify that user exist in the database (and the password) and only then username is saved to the session....I am testing the login process

Comment: if you are testing the login process.. might i suggest using selenium. You can use it without any coding via a Firefox plugin called selenium builder.

Comment: PS - I have to tell you that you cannot access a session variable of another page via curl. Just not possible. Curl is just loading up a web address, and returning the output. The most curl can do is save the cookies that site set, and use them for the next post. So it COULD keep you logged in for your next post, look into curls cookiejar options if this is what you are trying to do.